# Codeigniter HMVC loading custom config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-hmvc

Im using HMVC extension in CodeIgniter. Where i have a module like

```
 moduleName
     config 
         config.php
         routes.php
     controller
         test.php
     models
         etc..
```

from `test.php` i was trying to load custom config item from above module folder.
But its not working. im extending my class like `class Test extends MX_Controller {}`

I tried loading config item from default config folder which is outside the module folder and `its working`

According to [this post](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/215771/#998024), module config should load when module is initialized. But its not working.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Codeignitor dose not load the config from modules folder by default. Its look on application/config folder, First its look on the ENVIRONMENT folder  in case you have application/config/development .....

To load the config form the module you can use

```
$this->load->config('../models/config/XXX.php')
```

Or you have to extend the Config class to modify your way